# How to find the count of a variable that has coded Y or N for the sub-variable for the main variable?

Tags: excel, count

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjOLt.jpg)In the below excel file, I have 3 stems. Each stem has different no of nodes (for 1st stem, 7 nodes and so on..) and each node infestation is coded Y or N. Now how can I calculate how many stem is infected from this data

```
stem node   node infested
1    1       N
1    2       Y
1    3       Y
1    4       Y
1    5       N
1    6       N
1    7       N
2    1       N
2    2       Y
2    3       Y
2    4       N
2    5       N
2    6       N
2    7       N
3    1       N  
3    2       Y
3    3       N
3    4       N
3    5       N
3    6       N
```

Comment: How is this not the simplest COUNTIF question?

Comment: Maybe you need to learn some basic Excel functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the number of unique stems that has at least one infested node and using [this ressource](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3403-excel-count-unique-based-on-another-column.html)

`{=SUMPRODUCT((($C$2:$C$21="Y"))/COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$21,$C$2:$C$21&"",$A$2:$A$21,$A$2:$A$21&""))}`

Used like this:

[image]